# Laravel XXS Filter - and passing "withInput" back to form

Tags: php, laravel

Iam a bit confused, just installed an [XSS Filter Package](https://github.com/FrozenNode/XssInput) for Laravel.
Like mentioned in documentation i have enabled auto-filtering, works.

But when i use the following Code to process form input:

```
    $input = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($input, Comment::rules());
    // do some validation

    // not passed:
    return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->withInput();
```

than the "bad" code is passed back to the form. For testing i have added

```
->withInput($input);
```

now the "bad" code is filtered.

Now to my question why? What is the source for withInput when i don't pass an the input to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the laravel withInput function -

```
public function withInput(array $input = null)
{
    $input = $input ?: $this->request->input();

    $this->session->flashInput($input);

    return $this;
}
```

as you can see it check if the `input` variable is null then it runs a function to obtain all inputs.

The following package doesn't override the request->input() function then it doesn't take any effect on it.

You should leave it as a default as your users wouldn't want to see their data being escaped that something you should do behind the scenes unless you know what your doing.